# is this valid yaml?

Tags: yaml, yaml-cpp

```
items:
    house:
        - bathroom:
            - toothbrush
            - soap
        - bedroom:
            - bed:
                - pillow
                - sheet
            - closet:
                - clothes:
                    - underwear
                    - socks
    garden:
        - treehouse:
            - toys:
                - nerfgun
                - car
            - window

        - garage:
            - car
            - toolbox:
                - hammer
                - scewdriver
                - pliers
            - lawnmower
```

Here is another try at this document, it has no compound list (I guess that's how it's called).

```
items2:
    house:
        - bathroom:
            - toothbrush
            - soap
        - bedroom:
            - bed:
                - pillow
                - sheet
            - closet:
                - clothes:
                    - underwear
                    - socks
```

Which of those two yaml documents are valid ? I'm still wondering if I can use a list of keyed lists like that (nested list ?):

```
items:
    - list1:
        -itemA
        -itemB
    - list2:
        -itemC
        -itemD
```

Comment: so it's valid yaml, but it's not doing what I thought it would do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this to check if your yaml is ok: [yamlint](http://yamllint.com/)

It's seems ok.

Comment: I don't understand why it put a new line after dashes

Comment: well i dont no either. For the presentation maybe ? Anyway your yaml is still valid.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's valid YAML (well, the first two are; in the third, make sure that you have a space after your `-` in the sequences); but it may not do exactly what you think. In your toy example

```
items:
    - list1:
        - itemA
        - itemB
    - list2:
        - itemC
        - itemD
```

the value associated with `items` is a sequence; and each entry of that sequence is a map with a single key/value pair (for the first entry, the key is `list1`, and in the second, `list2`).

What may have confused you in your first real example was how to access each element. Since you tagged this `yaml-cpp`, here's how you would get, say, the list of the toys in the greenhouse of your first example:

```
doc["items"]["garden"][0]["treehouse"][0]["toys"];
```

(Note the `[0]` before accessing the "treehouse" and "toys" keys.)